# How To Store data from the user in my variables by Immediate presses from the keyboard in C++ and C#(without pressing enter)

Tags: c#, c++, input

I don't know if this might be an-already answered question, 
if i wanna make a touch-typing program, It should be made key-sensitive,
I mean, everytime I press a key, it gets compared with the text that I'm writing.

now I can't just do something like: cin >> something; or Console.ReadLine(something);
these won't work till I press enter which is i don't want..

how can I make the input work the way i want to in C++ && C# ?

ThanX in Advance :)

Comment: You should do a Google search for "event based keyboard input", which is what you seem to want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For C#:

Try using `Console.ReadKey`, which "Obtains the next character or function key pressed by the user."

You can see msdn sample:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "conio.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char c;
    getch(c);
    cout << endl << c << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

conio.h is deprecated I believe, but getch() is one of the easiest ways to get unbuffered, unechoed character presses. I have used it in many a game I've made.

Comment: getch is deprectaed, you can use getchar(). http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/getchar/

Comment: well, getchar() isn't really what I'm looking for,
instead, getch() worked better :)

Comment: char x;
while(true){
 x = getch();
 if(x == '~') break;
 cout << x;
}

Comment: but i just have one more thing ..
is there a function that returns the x coordinate of the current position of the cursor in c++ ?

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please mark it as such. As far as mouse input goes: reading it from the command line is extremely complicated. I suggest working with SDL or something if you want to track mouse movement. http://www.libsdl.org/